# How to send data between two iOS apps (in different devices) using bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

I am making an app to control the an iOS app (A) in a device remotely from another iOS device using another app(B). App B will send some data to A and B will get the response data from A. The data might be text or images. This data transmission can be done by using bluetooth.

So the problem is once A and B gets connected. In the next launch both should be connected automatically if they are in the available bluetooth range.

I go through Game-kit , Multi-peer connectivity, core bluetooth, externalAccessory frameworks. What i observed from these.

Using GameKit and multi-peer connectivity frameworks every time we should send and accept the invitation in different devices.

And from core bluetooth we can send data only and can't receive data except we implement the two way peripheral and central.

And from external Accessory framework we can access an iOS device from an external peripheral.(I think the classic bluetooth can be implemented using externalAccessory framework)

So what my question how can i accomplish this.And can i achieve the above using Bonjour via bluetooth?. And I am right for the details.If not correct me. and guide me in the proper direction to achieve this.

Comment: Core Bluetooth is probably the most applicable - You will need to implement both a peripheral and a central in your app

Comment: can i use classic bluetooth and bonjour over bluetooth.@Paulw11

Comment: Yes, but only via Multipeer Connectivity Framework